# Can every sequence that does not have an explicitly stated domain be one of infinitely many possible functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics

The following is an excerpt from a discrete mathematics text:

> A sequence is a function from a subset of the set of integers (usually
>   either the set {0, 1, 2, …}  or the set {1, 2, 3, …}) to a set S. We
>   use the notation an to denote the image of the integer n.  We call an
>   a term of the sequence. We describe sequences by listing the terms of
>   the sequence in order of increasing subscripts.

Rosen, Kenneth. Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th edition (p. 165). McGraw-Hill Higher Education.

Based on that excerpt, it seems that sequences (which are just functions) can have domains like the set {1, -4, 36, 109} (which is, surprisingly to me, **neither a set of non-negative integers nor a set of consecutive integers**). It also seems that, if that is true, then the sequence Q = 1.6, 4, 9, 16
can be interpreted as any function with an assignment arrangement that includes any integer-containing domain, as long as 1 is assigned to the lowest element of that domain, 4 is assigned to the second lowest element, 9 is assigned to the third lowest element, etc.

For example, a possible interpretation of sequence Q might be -4 -> 1.6; 1 -> 4; 36 -> 9; and 109 -> 16.

Is the extracted definition of a sequence a correct one? Also, is my reasoning valid, and, if so, should I always specify the domain of a sequence [perhaps using the same notation that I would use for a function (Sequence S : {integers} -> **R**] along with its enumeration?

Comment: I think Rosen may be a little careless here. I'd insist the domain be a "connected" set of integers (an *interval* of integers). Have you looked at any other texts/sources to see what definitions they give?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I can live with that definition, but I’d actually prefer to allow the domain to be any set of integers that is bounded below. Given a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and an arbitrary (generally infinite) $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, I want to be able to say that $\langle x_n:n\in\A\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$.

Comment: @Brian you'd rule out "doubly-infinite" sequences $\dots,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$?

Comment: @Gerry: No, but I’d insist on clearly identifying them as something other than default sequences, just as I’m generally very careful to specify **finite** sequence when that’s what I have in mind.  Unless the context is overwhelmingly clear, I’d not use the unmodified term *sequence* for either doubly-infinite or finite sequences.